# Cannot run one-off process at this time message on Heroku (DJango)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, heroku

After setting up Heroku with DJango, I tried to use the following command:

`heroku run manage.py`

This resulted in "Cannot run one-off process at this time. Please try again later".

Do I just have to try again later? Or does it require some action on my part?

Thanks!

Comment: …you posted this 16 hours ago. Have you tried running the command again?

Comment: Did you have any luck with this? I ran into the same problem. I also tried `heroku run python manage.py migrate` but get the same result.

Comment: Just re-run the command later. It should work. It did for me.